# Is lucene calling datasource for every request?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, lucene

I am new to Apache Lucene. Please someone guide me how apache lucene works.
For every request, will it invoke datasource(documents, database. etc) from lucene index?
or it will look at the index alone?

Comment: Have you tried a google search?

Answer (score 2):

Once documents are indexed, Lucene will only look at the index and nowhere else.

You also need to understand the difference between *indexing* and *storing* data in the index. Former allows document to be *found* while latter allows the data to be *read* when relevant document is found.

Why is this necessary? Sometimes you can index all fields but only store the ID and retrieve the actual data from external source (e.g. database) using that ID. Or you can store data in the index and load it from there instead of going to another data source.